# Create a role in customized role in GCP for Kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to create a customized role in GCP for the GKE cluster which only has permissions to create.

I have added the following permission. Please advise or please give any reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsNYq.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to create a custom role which gives permission only to create a GKE cluster.

You can add the `Container.clusters.create` role will help you to do the same. For more IAM roles check this [document](https://darkbit.io/blog/kubernetes-engine-iam-roles).

Following link will help u to create a custom role :

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles